# Custom js-data formatter for moment dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs, jsonschema, jsdata

I'm working with `JS-Data` and I would love to figure out the best way to go about writing a validator / formatter potentially for the Schema to handle date strings as moment objects. It would be great if I could validate a date property as a moment object, and then serialize / deserialize using moment to manage all date / time objects

Has anyone tackled this with `JS-Data`?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in the lifecycle hooks ie `beforeCreate` and `beforeUpdate`